# How to add a preload tag to a page-hero image in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagespeed, preload

the pagespeed reports states that my LCP is too high. The reason for this is my large page-hero. I want to implement a preload tag to the background-image, so that it gets rendered before the other elements in the viewport (h1, breadcrumbs etc.), to reduce the LCP-time.

Not exactly sure how this works in wordpress. I suppose one could make an edit in the functions.php oder singular.php file?

Sadly im not exactly a developer and would be super grateful if somebody could help me out with this issue:

This is the element that needs to be preloaded in the html:

Comment: <div class="cover-header bg-image" style="background-image: url( " https.//exampl.com" );">